# How do I get Landscape to apply USNs to client?

Tags: virtualbox, amazon-ec2, landscape, aws

I'm testing out an LDS system on AWS, and one of my client machines, another EC2 instance running 16.04, which has its security group configured to allow HTTPS and HTTP from my server's elastic IP, isn't updating its USNs and hasn't since the client was set up three days ago. However, the other client I'm using, a VirtualBox VM running 18.04, is doing that just fine. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I used landscape-server-quickstart to create the server, so could it be something misconfigured there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what to do. Simply removing and re-adding the computer from Landscape fixed it for me, bizarrely enough.